# Color.yellow.ignoresSafeArea()

Tags: swiftui

swift ui で

Color.yellow.ignoresSafeArea()

を置くと

画面全体ではなく

画面の下部だけに色が付きます。

配置場所がおかしいのでしょうか。

var body: some View {
Color.yellow.ignoresSafeArea()
}

としています。

Comment: ご提示のコードを、そのままXcodeのSwiftUIのプレビューに表示してみましたが、プレビューの画面全体が黄色になり「画面全体ではなく　画面の下部だけに色が付」く現象は起きませんでした。質問文に載せていない、他の箇所のコードが影響しているのではないでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。var body: some View { の一番上に持ってくると上部だけが黄色になります。

Comment: 「一番上」ということは、`Color`以外の`View`が含まれているということですね。`Color`単独なら、「画面の下部だけに色が付」く現象は起きないはずです。それをまず質問者さんご自身で確認ください。そして、`Color`以外の`View`を削除したり、いったん削除したものを戻したりして、何度も試行錯誤していけば、何が原因で、どうしたら意図通りの結果になるか、見えてくるはずです。プログラミングの学習者は、誰もそうやって自身で調べ、問題を克服してきました。ご質問者さんも頑張ってトライしてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

このPreviewが動くはずなので、別のViewが原因かと思われます。

```swift
struct ContentView_Preview: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    Color.yellow.ignoresSafeArea()
  }
}
```